# nginx testing with ab not working with high number of concurrent connections

Tags: server, nginx

I have installed nginx and php-fpm on a 64-bit Ubuntu Server 11.10. The server works fine but I am trying to test the server (using ab) with 10,000 concurrent connections. When I try it I get `socket: Too many open files (24)`.

I have tried some changes involving pam.d and the security conf but nothing worked.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Post your nginx config and try running nginx without php-fpm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solutions. I was looking at all wrong. nginx was not giving any errors. It was the Ubuntu client where I was running ab that was giving an error. The server was fine.

Solution (to be executed on the client i.e. the machine where you are running ab:

```
sudo su
```

this is to be root

```
ulimit -n 20000
```

this is to allow more than 10000 connections. I chose 20000 randomly.

Note that theses are not permanent settings and will be reset once you reboot.

Check out the below post for some more tweaks on the client side - https://serverfault.com/questions/10852/what-limits-the-maximum-number-of-connections-on-a-linux-server